# Labels and buttons not appearing PyQt5, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class MyWin:
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(200,200,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("First Label")
        self.label.move(100, 100)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Button")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.click)

    def click(self):
        self.label.setText("Pressed ha")
        


def window():
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

I am a beginner in PyQt5, and I'm having an issue with my program. When this code is executed, a window appears; however, the label and the button does not appear. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating an instance of your class, which should also inherit from QMainWindow, as right now it's just a simple python `object` subclass.

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...

def window():
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWin()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much!